# Xcode organiser - Upload to App Store button is disable

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 9.0.1 (9A1004). I'm wanting to release my app store but the upload button is greyed out. I have tried various things, like adding and removing my account from the xcode preferences, un checking manage code signing etc. I did notice that when I open the archive it has two projects inside. I was expecting them to be bundled together in the one .ipa file.

I have read some of the posts on SO and tried various things. I was hoping that if anyone had some experience with this issue? Or some ideas on how to solve it?

thanks again

[image: Archive screen]

Comment: free or premium ???

Comment: I have a subscription